# Mathematica Input to get the exact form

Tags: number-representation

> **Question:** Is there a command in mathematica that can take a decimal input, and output it into its exact form?

The question arose when I tried to use this command:

```
x = NSolve[Sum[h(An+B)/(C^n) /. A →(3/2)Sqrt[2]  /. C→ -2^9 /. h → (2n)!^3 / n!^6, 
    {n, 0, 50}] == 1/Pi, B, 30]
```

And got a decimal output of approximately $0.353553390593\ldots$. According to [this website (where I got the approximation from)](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0013), that is equal to $(1/4)\sqrt2$.

And my Mathematica does not recognize the command **Recognize[x,k,v]** so I am completely lost.

I am also relatively new to Mathematica. The output of the code *should* give $0.353553390593\ldots$ But whenever I enter it in, I get a bunch of errors that say this is protected. When I change the variables, I get an approximation greater than $1$. What is wrong with the coding that I'm entering in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RootApproximant[0.353553390593, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Rationalize` may sometimes of use too:

```
Rationalize[0.353553390593, 0.00001]
(* 134/379 *)

% // N
(* 0.353562 *)
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to add what was wrong with my piece of coding? Everything seems alright, yet Mathematica says some things are protected and there is an error dispatch...

Comment: @Frank Unless you still have Mathematica version 5 (current version is 11.01) ``NumberTheory`Recognize` `` won't work for you. See [http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/NumberTheory/Recognize.html](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Compatibility/tutorial/NumberTheory/Recognize.html).

Comment: No, I meant this:
    x = NSolve[Sum[h(An+B)/C^n /. A →(3/2)Sqrt[2]  /. C→ -2^9 /. h → (2n)!^3 / n!^6, {n, 0, 50}] == 1/Pi, B, 30]

Comment: @Frank Seperate An and Cn with a space to make it a multiplication, and don't create an arrow symbol from outside of Mathematica. Use -> (Mathematica will replace it automatically with an arrow if you type the next character). Also, don't use uppercase variables as they may conflict with built-ins (C is one).

Comment: Okay, I did that with x = NSolve[Sum[h(pn+q)/r^n /. p ->(3/2)Sqrt[2] /. r-> -2^9 /. h -> ((2n)!^3) / (n!^6), {n, 0, 50}] == 1/Pi, q, 30] and got the output $q$ as $q=1.0150800842861232878334064341(0.318\ldots - 0.98\ldots pn)$ With the $\ldots$ meaning a significant amount of other characters. I'm confused, because this doesn't give the number I was looking for.

Comment: @Frank Because you have `pn` which should be `p*n` (or `p n` - the space is interchangeable with `*`).

Comment: @corey979 ooohhhh!!! Thank you! Now it works...